# Spring data neo4j -- tx.close() lasts too long

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to import data from the relational database into neo4j. The process goes like this (simplified a little bit):

```
while (!sarBatchService.isFinished()) {

        logger.info("New batch started");

        Date loadDeklFrom = sarBatchService.getStartDateForNewBatch();
        Date loadDeklTo = sarBatchService
                .getEndDateForNewBatch(loadDeklFrom);   // = loadDeklFrom + 2 hours

        logger.info("Dates calculated");

        Date startTime = new Date();

        List<Dek> deks = dekLoadManager
                .loadAllDeks(loadDeklFrom, loadDeklTo); // loading data from the relational database (POINT A)

        Date endLoadTime = new Date();

        logger.info("Deks loaded");

        GraphDatabase gdb = template.getGraphDatabase();
        Transaction tx = gdb.beginTx();

        logger.info("Transaction started!");

        try {

            for (Deks dek : deks) {

                /* transform dek into nodes, and save 
                this nodes with Neo4jTemplate.save() */
            }

            logger.info("Deks saved");

            Date endImportTime = new Date();

            int aff = sarBatchService.insertBatchData(loadDeklFrom,
                    loadDeklTo, startTime, endLoadTime, endImportTime,
                    deks.size()); // (POINT B)
            if (aff != 1) {
                String msg = "Something went wrong",

                throw new RuntimeException(msg);
            }

            logger.info("Batch data saved into relational database");

            tx.success();

            logger.info("Transaction marked as success.");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException
                | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
                | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException
                | InvocationTargetException e1) {

            logger.error("Something bad happend :(");
            logger.error(e1.getStackTrace().toString());
        } finally {
            logger.info("Closing transaction...");

            tx.close(); // (POINT C)

            logger.info("Transaction closed!");
            logger.info("Need more work? " + !sarBatchService.isFinished());
        }
    }
```

So, data in the relational database has a timestamp which indicates when it's stored and I'm loading it in two hours by two hours time intervals (**POINT A** in the code). After that, I'm iterating through loaded data, transforming it into nodes (spring-data-neo4j nodes), storing in neo4j and storing informations about the current batch (**POINT B**) in the relational database. I'm logging almost every step to debug more easily.

The program successfully finishes 158 batches. The problem starts as the 159th batch starts. The program stops at the **POINT C** in the code (tx.close()) and waits there for 4 hours (which usually lasts a few seconds). After that continues normally.

I've tried running it on tomcat 7 with 10GB heap size and 4GB heap size. The result is the same (blocks on 159th batch). The maximum number of nodes in one transaction is between 10k and 15k (7k on average), and the 159th batch has less then 10k nodes.

The interesting part is that everything goes well if the data is loaded 4 by 4 hours or 12 by 12 hours. Also, if I restart Tomcat or execute only the 159th batch everything passes without problems.

I'm using spring 3.2.8 with spring-data-neo4j 3.0.2.

This is the neo4j's message.log:

```
...
2014-11-24 15:21:38.080+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application    threads blocked for an additional 418ms [total block time: 150.973s]
2014-11-24 15:21:45.722+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 377ms [total block time: 151.35s]
...
2014-11-24 15:23:57.381+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 392ms [total block time: 156.593s]
2014-11-24 15:24:06.758+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotating     [/home/pravila/data/neo4j/nioneo_logical.log.1] @ version=22 to   /home/pravila/data/neo4j/nioneo_logical.log.2 from position 26214444
2014-11-24 15:24:06.763+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate log first start entry @ pos=24149878 out of [339=Start[339,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|5889317606667601380|364|-1],  BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-11-24    15:23:13.021+0000/1416842593021,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=267]]
2014-11-24 15:24:07.401+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate: old log scanned, newLog @ pos=2064582
2014-11-24 15:24:07.402+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Log rotated, newLog @ pos=2064582, version 23 and last tx 267
2014-11-24 15:24:07.684+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotating [/home/pravila/data/neo4j/index/lucene.log.1] @ version=6 to /home/pravila/data/neo4j/index/lucene.log.2 from position 26214408
2014-11-24 15:24:07.772+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate log first start entry @ pos=25902494 out of [134=Start[134,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|5889317606667601380|364|-1], BranchId[ 49 54 50 51 55 52 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-11-24     15:23:13.023+0000/1416842593023,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=133]]
2014-11-24 15:24:07.871+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate: old log scanned, newLog @ pos=311930
2014-11-24 15:24:07.878+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Log rotated, newLog @ pos=311930, version 7 and last tx 133
2014-11-24 15:24:10.919+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 214ms [total block time: 156.807s]
2014-11-24 15:24:17.486+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 405ms [total block time: 157.212s]
...
2014-11-24 15:25:28.692+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 195ms [total block time: 159.316s]
2014-11-24 15:25:33.238+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotating [/home/pravila/data/neo4j/nioneo_logical.log.2] @ version=23 to /home/pravila/data/neo4j/nioneo_logical.log.1 from position 26214459
2014-11-24 15:25:33.242+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate log first start entry @ pos=24835943 out of [349=Start[349,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|-6436474643536791121|374|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-11-24 15:25:27.038+0000/1416842727038,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=277]]
2014-11-24 15:25:33.761+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Rotate: old log scanned, newLog @ pos=1378532
2014-11-24 15:25:33.763+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Log rotated, newLog @ pos=1378532, version 24 and last tx 277
2014-11-24 15:25:37.031+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 148ms [total block time: 159.464s]
2014-11-24 15:25:45.891+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 153ms [total block time: 159.617s]
....    
2014-11-24 15:26:48.447+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 221ms [total block time: 161.641s]
```

I don't know what's going on here...

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after hours an hours of searching and testing I tried to rerun the whole batch with the 4 by 4 hours time interval. It also stopped after the 145th batch (transaction). The difference was that it threw an error (**Too many opened files**). I set the ulimit for opened files to unlimited and now it works. The only mystery is why the program didn't throw an error the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It very much looks like you have a leaking perhaps outer transaction there.

So that the inner transaction that you show actually finishes but the outer one continues to accumulate state. As Neo doesn't suspend outer transactions but purely nests them there will be no real commit until you hit the outer `tx.success(); tx.close();`

You should see it if you take thread dump when it blocks to see if it is actually stuck in commit.

Comment: Hi Michael, tnx for your reply. The while loop I wrote is basically the whole body of the function (scheduled function). I haven't explicitly opened any other transaction except the one inside the loop. Is it still possible that there is an outer neo4j transaction? Also, I've never read the thread dump. I executed kill -3 [tomcat pid] and now I have a big file which I don't now how to read :) What should I search for?

Comment: I tried to run the 4 by 4 hours batch and it also stopped, on the 145th transaction. Looks like the program has difficulties opening and closing a lot of transactions in a row.